# Постановка запятой перед «как»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, обороты-с-как

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед «как» в предложении "Я хочу стремиться рисовать(,) как знаменитые люди".

Comment: Человек хочет рисовать, или он хочет стремиться?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае запятая ставится, это обособленный сравнительный оборот.

После редактирования:

(1)  *Я хочу научиться **рисовАть**, **как знаменИтые люди**.* Здесь два ударения— на глаголе и на обороте. Пропущенное указательное местоимение ***так*** подразумевается.

Оборот  не обособляется при наличии однородных членов:

(2)  *Я хочу научиться рисовать как знаменИтые люди, а не как обыкновенные исполнители заказов*. Здесь ударение падает только на оборот, который становится центром высказывания.